# Can you get the size of the Flash object in Actionscript?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm working with a Flash movie and I'm trying to get the size of the player itself (i.e. the height and width Flash has to work with from the object/embed tag). As far as I can tell, Flash doesn't make this available to ActionScript.

I'm able to use `this.root.loaderInfo.width` and `this.root.loaderInfo.height` to get the "intended" size of the flash movie (what's specified on export), but if the dimensions are different on the page, this isn't helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `stage.stageWidth` and `stage.stageHeight`. You have to set `stage.scaleMode` to `StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE` for those to work.

Comment: That, too, delivers the "intended" size, not the actual size.

Comment: I'm actually pretty sure this gives you the dimension of the player's stage. try stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, ...) and see if the size you're looking for ever comes up.

Comment: The event doesn't fire in the browser, though it will in the standalone Flash Player (and it gives the right numbers, too) -- but I'm getting nothing in the browser, even if I deliberately resize the object after loading using JavaScript.

Comment: Is you stage.scaleMode is to StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE?

Comment: Ah! No, it's not--and setting it to that makes it work now. Thanks!